# Android: Need helping in XML aligning my listView's top to be below the tabLayout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

Currently my listView appears over the TabLayout but I need the listView to appear below the tabLayout obviously.

I tried moving around the listView in several positions in XML design component tree, but other positions when I ran the app, made content of other XML files appear in front of my listView and that's NOT good. So this is the only positions for component tree that i've tested that everything works except for the listView covering the TabLayout part.

This is what I have:

[image]

The following is the code for this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout




    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CBAEFF"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

        />



    <com.example.myname.appname.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_xhdpi"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_info"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/color_press_navigation"
    android:id="@+id/Navigation_header"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"


    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">



   </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="174dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        />
     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What do I change in the above XML code to make the listView appear below the TabLayout?

Comment: put your activity layout in your question, not the content layout

Comment: I added the entire XML layout in my activity_main.xml in question.

Comment: you have a tablayout with viewpager, this will show all your screen, where do you want to put the listview?

Comment: I want to leave the listView on top of all views as you see in the picture above, only I want to move it below the TabLayout because currently when I click on my searchView to open listView, the listView appears on top of the tabLayout and that's not good.

Comment: where do you want to put the CustomViewPager ?

Comment: I want everything else to stay as is, only move the listView below the tabLayout so the TabLayout is shown.

Comment: use a relative layout :)   Relative > tablayout top ,  listview below tablelayout

Comment: Is anything I can move in the listView code in XML file that'd place the listView below Tablayout as opposed to changing an entire layout?

Comment: no bro, because you are using coordinatorlayout as parent

Comment: With RelativeLayout it seems to do the same thing, I'm currently using it now for listView. ListView still overlaps the TabLayout.

Comment: Only if I added something like    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" then it works, but won't it look weird on different size phones in the "normal" size phones?

Comment: you need to change your layout as I said. Use RelativeLayout

Comment: I did change to RelativeLayout. I added the android:layout_marginTop="46dp" in RelativeLayout.